# Can't display fractions in React project. Child error instead even with mathjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fractions, math.js

I want to create my own recipe converter and needed partial quantities of measurements like cups and teaspoons in fractions. When I attempted to insert these as portions into an object as shown below, it displays a decimal on the webpage instead of a ratio as desired.

```
export const ingredients = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'rice wine vinegar (or sub apple cider vinegar)',
    category: 'Pickled Vegetables',
    portion: 2/3,
    unit: 'cup',
},
```

After research, I have discovered the npm module mathjs and downloaded it in an attempt resolve my issue.

However after adding this code, (which appears to work on its own)

```
const math = require('mathjs')

math.config({
     number: 'Fraction'
})
```

And then this code

```
export const ingredients = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'rice wine vinegar (or sub apple cider vinegar)',
    category: 'Pickled Vegetables',

//portion value has changed
    portion: math.fraction(`2/3`),
    unit: 'cup',
},
```

Which I had copied from the Fraction example from the module's [website](http://mathjs.org/examples/fractions.js.html) I have received the error that this Object is not a valid React child and to use an array instead.

Based off of what I had seen from the website, it seemed as though not having this value in an array was perfectly fine.

I also tried placing the / in '' but it was not accepted by VS Code

```
portion: 2'/'3,
```

The text editor explained that this was incorrect syntax and now I am at a loss.

What is wrong with my code and am I on the right track to working with fractions?

Comment: The result of `math.fraction()` is probably an object. Objects can't be rendered. You probably need to convert it to a string first or whatever representation you want it to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're only doing half the formatting...

Try this:

```
/* for readability let's declare two thirds first */
const twoThirds = math.format(math.fraction('2/3'), { fraction: 'ratio' })

export const ingredients = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'rice wine vinegar (or sub apple cider vinegar)',
    category: 'Pickled Vegetables',

//portion value has changed
    portion: twoThirds,
    unit: 'cup',
},
```

[The MathJs example page shows all fraction options](http://mathjs.org/examples/fractions.js.html)

Comment: Jeez, I swore I tried that and it didn't work before. Thank you, I must've not done the ratio portion when I made the const.

Comment: Just did! Thank you again this was giving me a huge headache.